# Regular expression to annotate ordinal numbers

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, nltk, tokenize

I am trying to match the result of this doctest in python by inputting the correct regular expression.

This is what i have so far:

```
import re
import nltk
import collections
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('gutenberg')
nltk.download('brown')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
nltk.download('universal_tagset')

regexp = re.compile('[0-9]+$')

def annotateOD(listoftokens):
    """Annotate the ordinal numbers in the list of tokens
    >>> annotateOD("the second tooth".split())
    [('the', ''), ('second', 'OD'), ('tooth', '')]
    """

    result = []
    for t in listoftokens:
        if regexp.match(t):
            result.append((t, 'OD'))
        else:
            result.append((t, ''))
    return result


# DO NOT MODIFY THE CODE BELOW

def compute_f1(result, tagged):
    assert len(result) == len(tagged) # This is a check that the length of the result and tagged are equal
    correct = [result[i][0] for i in range(len(result)) if result[i][1][:2] == 'OD' and tagged[i][1][:2] == 'OD']
    numbers_result = [result[i][0] for i in range(len(result)) if result[i][1][:2] == 'OD']
    numbers_tagged = [tagged[i][0] for i in range(len(tagged)) if tagged[i][1][:2] == 'OD']
    if len(numbers_tagged) > 0:
        r = len(correct)/len(numbers_tagged)
    else:
        r = 0.0
    if len(numbers_result) > 0:
        p = len(correct)/len(numbers_result)
    else:
        p = 0.0
    return 2*r*p/(r+p)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
    nltk.download('brown')
    tagged = nltk.corpus.brown.tagged_words(categories='news')
    words = [t for t, w in tagged]
    result = annotateOD(words)
    f1 = compute_f1(result, tagged)
    print("F1 score:", f1)
```

The result I have is:

```
Expected :[('the', ''), ('second', 'OD'), ('tooth', '')]

Actual   :[('the', ''), ('second', ''), ('tooth', '')]
```

Then I tried a different approach and tried this regular expression:

```
regexp = re.compile('.*(st|nd|rd|th)$')
```

and got this as the result:

```
Expected :[('the', ''), ('second', 'OD'), ('tooth', '')]

Actual   :[('the', ''), ('second', 'OD'), ('tooth', 'OD')]
```

I've spent quite a long time trying to pass the doctest but there always is that ONE that doesn't match.

Comment: WOW it worked! Can't believe that's all it took, forgive me I'm VERY new at regex. I kinda feel silly and noob after all my efforts in trying to do this. Thank you again my good sir

Comment: But tell me how and why this works? Is this only a solution to solve for this particular doctest?

Comment: Read https://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/vocabulary/numbers/ordinal  - try to get behind the rules of how to formulate them and then build a regex that fits them all. Might be as cumbersome as `'first|second|thirth|fourth|fifth|sixth|..|ninety-ninth'` or come up with something smarter.